# How does the never type work in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I often stumble on the `never` type in TypeScript. While I've read the docs, looked through existing questions on SO - my understanding still isn't great. I'd love some help understanding it better. Here's an example from the TS docs that has my head spinning:

```
type GetReturnType<Type> = Type extends (...args: never[]) => infer Return
  ? Return
  : never;

type Num = GetReturnType<() => number>;

type Str = GetReturnType<(x: string) => string>;

type Bools = GetReturnType<(a: boolean, b: boolean) => boolean[]>;
```

My understanding would be that specifying `(...args: never[]) => ...` would mean creating a function signature that does not accept any arguments (why `never[]`?). Yet `Str` and `Bools` are both function signatures with arguments (shouldn't this error?).

I'm also struggling to understand the conditional type: `infer Return ? Return : never`. To me this means that the function either has a return value or the compiler should produce an error. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`never` is a [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type). What that means is that `never` is a type with no values, and it is a subtype of every other type. If you imagine that a type corresponds to a set of values which are assignable to that type, then `never` corresponds to the [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set).

> My understanding would be that specifying `(...args: never[]) => ...` would mean creating a function signature that does not accept any arguments (why `never[]`?).

Technically you are almost correct; an array of type `never[]` cannot contain any values, but an empty array *is* assignable to type `never[]`, because [all zero of its elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) are of type `never`. So technically a function of type `(...args: never[]) => ...` can be called with zero arguments.

That said, that's not really what's going on here. To understand `T extends (...args: never[]) => infer R`, we need to talk about [covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). For the sake of explanation, let's suppose that we have two types, `Animal` and `Dog`, and `Dog` is a subtype of `Animal`:

- First consider the function types `() => Animal` and `() => Dog`, which we'll call `GetAnimal` and `GetDog` respectively. A `GetAnimal` is a function which can be called to get an `Animal`; a `GetDog` can be called to get an `Animal`, because a `Dog` is an `Animal`, so therefore (by the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)) `GetDog` is a subtype of `GetAnimal`. This means function types are *covariant* with their return types, because if you replace a function's return type with a subtype, then you get a subtype of the original function type. (And vice versa, if you replace the return type with a supertype, then you get a supertype of the original function type.)
- Now consider the types `(a: Animal) => void` and `(a: Dog) => void`, which we'll call `TakeAnimal` and `TakeDog` respectively. A `TakeDog` is a function which cannot necessarily accept any `Animal`, so you cannot use a `TakeDog` anywhere a `TakeAnimal` is required; this means `TakeDog` is not a subtype of `TakeAnimal`. On the other hand, a `TakeAnimal` is a function which can accept any type of animal, including a `Dog`, so it *is* a function which accepts a `Dog`, and therefore (by the LSP again) `TakeAnimal` is a subtype of `TakeDog`. This means function types are *contravariant* with their parameter types, because if you replace a function's parameter type with a *supertype*, then you get a *subtype* of the original function type. (And vice versa, if you replace the parameter type with a subtype, then you get a supertype of the original function type.)

What this boils down to is that the function type `(...args: never[]) => R` is a *supertype* of all other function types which return `R`, because `never[]` is a subtype of every array type (because `never` is a subtype of every type, and array types are covariant with their component type), and it appears in contravariant position. So `T extends (...args: never[]) => ...` really means `T` can have any parameter types at all.

Personally I think this is a bad way of writing `GetReturnType`; it is more normal to write `T extends (...args: any) => ...` or `T extends (...args: any[]) => ...` because this is easier to understand, and also works. Note that Typescript has a built in helper type `ReturnType` which does the same thing as `GetReturnType`, and is defined this way:

```
type ReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any
```

In this definition, the type parameter `T` has `(...args: any) => any` as its upper bound, so you cannot use this to try to get the return type of something that isn't a function. Also, this means the `extends` clause of the conditional type is guaranteed to be satisfied, so the "false" branch (which was `never` in the definition you found) is guaranteed not to be used, so it doesn't matter what type is there (here it's `any`, but I think it would be clearer to write `never`).

> I'm also struggling to understand the conditional type: `infer Return ? Return : never`. To me this means that the function either has a return value or the compiler should produce an error. But I'm not sure.

As mentioned in the other answer, you've parsed this wrong; the whole `extends` clause is the condition, so this should be read as `(T extends (...args: never[]) => infer R) ? R : never`.

More pertinently, this doesn't mean the compiler should produce an error when the function has no return type; it means the result should be the type `never`, which does not result in an error, and is arguably the correct result. Think of it like this: if a value is assignable to `ReturnTypeOf<T>` then it should be possible for something of type `T` to return that value when you call it. If `T` isn't a function then it can't return any value because you can't call it, so `ReturnType<T>` should be an empty set.

Comment: This is literally the best explanation I've seen for this. Thank you for taking the time to write it down! This answer will be a reference that will be helpful to me for years (hopefully for others, too)!

Answer (score 7):

Usually `never` means *"this type, in this scope, cannot be used"*. This is useful when instantiating generic parameters that you do not need to know the type of. In this case, to get the return value of a function, its arguments do not matter. So they can safely be typed as `never`.

So `never[]` here means *"an array of some type, and please consider it a type error to assume it's any *specific* type"*.

This is preferable to `any[]` in this case because `any` lets you do *anything* with that type, and usually its use means a loss of type safety.

It's not so useful outside of generic type aliases. If you tried to use it more directly:

```
type Fn = (...args: never[]) => string
const fn: Fn = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => a.toFixed()
fn(123) // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
```

It allows the assignment for the same reason that `GetReturnType` works, but when you try to use or reference a `never`, you'll get a type error.

---

The second part of question is a completely different thing. First, you have the logic grouping incorrect. It's more like:

```
(Type extends (...args: never[]) => infer Return) ? Return : never
```

Or in psuedo code:

```
if (Type is subtype of ((...args: never[]) => infer Return) {
  use type Return
} else {
  use type never
}
```

`infer` lets you pull a deeply nested type from a larger type, but it *only* works inside a `A extends B` style ternary. When you see `infer`, think of the type as a pattern with a wildcard. Whatever that wildcard will be inferred as the type of whatever name you provide, and then that will be available in the positive side of the ternary.

A simpler example:

```
type HasCoolness<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }> = T extends { coolness: infer R } ? R : never
type TestA = HasCoolness<{ coolness: number }> // number
type TestB = HasCoolness<{ coolness: string }> // string
type TestC = HasCoolness<{ notCool: 'ugh' }> // never
```

That `HasCoolness` type infers the value of the `coolness` property and returns its type. If there is no property, `never` is returned indicating that the returned type is not valid for use.

So that all means this is doing:

```
type GetReturnType<Type> = Type extends (...args: never[]) => infer Return
  ? Return
  : never
```

the same thing, except instead of inferring a property it's inferring the return type of a function. Note that because `Type` is not constrained (i.e. its not `GetReturnType<Type extends SomeOtherType>`) then you could pass anything to it. But if you pass something that isn't a function, it wont fir the pattern, and the negative clause of the ternary will be used, which will result in `never`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFAOgwQwE4HMDOAXFHBAG4TYDaAugJRIB8U+w2AlnLgFADGA9nFZQAZnGLwkqTMTgBXALYAjSgBooS4qw5d1vYkv78ANhExwGiZpjTB+MdgA8IAExR1uYlAEYATAGYGAHogqABBPEUIOGAofhEoUEgoAHJ5ZUoUqHZ8En5YzHx8dlw4TCVTRP4oMBxMBQhgSjiEpOg08ky0FACAFgBWD242qAAJQoBhI2NSIoAeABUoCEcmuBdcgG8oKgBrCBAtNk5cGmI5OF24fgB3BABfZmQllbWNqG2BE1mibLgRZoAJSg9ygAH4oMDZJ1sMNwNAFhBWGEpON8FNvkj8HNPtMfrJFCpsCDmCESITKHDkojWAAhVGTPFYnFQL4zLFHHS4ElQMnaE5UhFI4ATBnopnzbbXEXTYgpOS4AAWWUevNCpAo2CAA)

Comment: "never is the absence of all type information" - this is highly misleading IMO. Surely `any` is the absence of all type information? `any` is what you literally get when you don't provide a type annotation, and `never` is only ever inferred when the compiler has enough type information to determine that no value would be consistent with the information it has.

Comment: "This is useful when instantiating generic parameters that you do not need to know the type of". But in your own example later in the answer, you (correctly) use `unknown` for exactly that purpose. If you had used `never` instead then it wouldn't have worked!

Comment: Yeah, I agree that first sentence may not be quite right. I’ve removed it. But changing the unknown to never does not work here because you DO need the type information of that parameter so that you can infer it. So I stand by that.

Comment: It's not about whether you "need the type information" of the parameter or not; suppose you have a type like `type GetA<T> = T extends {a: infer A, b: unknown} ? A : never`, then in this example you don't "need the type information" of the `b` property, but if you change it to `never` then `GetA<{a: number, b: string}>` won't work. The only reason `never` works in the OP's example is because it appears in contravariant position.

Comment: For another example closer to the original one, consider `type GetParameters<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => unknown ? A : never`. Again you don't "need the type information" for the function's return type, but if you change the `unknown` to `never` then it stops working, because it's in covariant position. So for the purpose you're talking about, `unknown` is generally correct in covariant position, and `never` works in contravariant position, but `any` works either way and is (IMO) more readable.

Comment: For completeness, here's `never` working in contravariant position even when you do "need the type information". `type GetParameters<T extends (...args: never[]) => unknown> = T extends (...args: infer A) => unknown ? A : never`

Comment: Indeed! Contravariance/Covariance appears to be a gap in my knowledge. I did take form inspiration from the `@typescript/no-explicit-any` eslint rule, however, that uses similar language in its auto fix suggestions: https://imgur.com/a/SVnXsn0