# TypeScript typing for function that transforms an object whose values are functions?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-conversion, typescript-typings, typing

How would I type the following `transformer` function?

```js
class MyClass {
  public id: string = ''
}

const instance = new MyClass()

function transformer(funcs) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(funcs)
     .map(([key, func]) => [key, func.bind(instance)])
  )
}
```

The crux of my conundrum: More than just passing muster with the linter and compiler, I want intelligent typing for this, such that passing in an object with various `string` keys bonded to `function` values (each which expect a `this` arg of type `MyClass`) gets transformed such that the output is identical to the input except that it's had its requisite `this` param "burnt-in," and this is *known* to the editor/linter/compiler.

In fact, I can't even solve for the simpler solitary case, a function that takes a single param of a `function` needing a `this` of type `MyClass`, along with any number of additional params, and a certain return type… and it spits back a `function` that's typed identically, except its `this` has been "burnt-in."

```js
function transform(fn) {
  return fn.bind(new MyClass())
}
```

Even partial answers or further insight would be helpful here! I'd think that we'd need some clever and deep use of generics here, but don't even exactly know where to start. And any answers that can point to further documentation or reference material on the concepts used are especially appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via using mapped types and a conditional type to strip the `this` param.  I also modified your `transformer` function to be generic on the instance but still require that the function's `this` argument is the type of the instance provided to avoid code dupe later on.  Here is my solution:

```
class MyClass {
  public id: string = ''
}

const instance = new MyClass()

type StripThisParam<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
    T extends (this: any, ...params: infer $RestParams) => any
        ? (...args: $RestParams) => ReturnType<T>
        : T;

function transformer<
    I,
    T extends Record<string, (this: I, ...otherArgs: any[]) => any>
>(instance: I, funcs: T): { [K in keyof T]: StripThisParam<T[K]> } {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(funcs)
     .map(([key, func]) => [key, func.bind(instance)])
  ) as any;
}

const foo = transformer(instance, {
    bar(this: MyClass, name: string, age: number) {
        console.log(this.id);
    }
});

foo.bar("hey", 23);
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oAcCuARiAJbDTEAmAXNBAC4BOxAdgObQC80A5NxgL4YMwAPbN65cXTDNgAU07RmcgO5wkKCAAoAlELrwcCgMqNiOACoALYhAAKYBmAC2AHgvQ5ADzpzmFGC0AOhDHVggaGXgAbQBdHU4APmgo5I4sbGgPb19-QLobCJTmeAAaaBCgnEcXIpYAMzkGaAASACU5egcnZwgEjmSojMzMgH5oYNCGcJp2zrpu2v7kjro8BmYLQzl3ROGR6BoLAG4herxZOmIxaEYZCHqRBmcm132ASVL97J8-AOgOqIGBRXPQmGxyloCrYaJ8KiERAUmgBBaZFKJxZbFeB7RJaFj0GTyWHlc6yIoWHQ0NDQaIAaUk0AA1nJ4CJ6llYjRTExLIVFm4LPTYsl+OgMgw5GsNtAAPIEABWcmAdCC9QYImcAFFmGZOlp9vKlSqgn49doycA+vsKs4wDgtFpoiyytBLfEkrSXaSLsAggQWBR8VIiXIdPEMglINjToJhGIJI8RIo7uJHs8msHCbI5OVMCMCI4oYUaAhkJAIOVmC45DQwSxWOUwKxa0o8M4CE0EvmDthROIRCA5EEQCJWMXbEFKDpTiNBPwZ2cRCJ-UWAERWVlr8oAJgAzDOgA)

Comment: Thank you so much! The answer above uses one of TS's built-ins to accomplish what you've described, but thanks so much for your answer, as you've seemed to have done what it does manually with your code snippet above! Gonna dissect it and learn from it, so thank you _tons_!

Answer (score 1):

A function type can include the type of `this` inside the function. For example:

```ts
const f: (this: MyClass, x: number) => string =
  function(this: MyClass, x: number): string { /* ... */}
```

There’s a builtin utility type [`OmitThisParameter`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omitthisparametertype) that can remove or ‘burn in’ this `this` parameter:

```ts
/**
 * Extracts the type of the 'this' parameter of a function type,
 * or 'unknown' if the function type has no 'this' parameter.
 */
type ThisParameterType<T> = T extends (this: infer U, ...args: never) => any
  ? U
  : unknown

/**
 * Removes the 'this' parameter from a function type.
 */
type OmitThisParameter<T> = unknown extends ThisParameterType<T>
  ? T
  : T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => R : T
```

You can type `transform` and `transformer` like this:

```ts
type MyClassFn = (this: MyClass, ...args: never[]) => unknown

function transform<F extends MyClassFn>(fn: F): OmitThisParameter<F> {
  // requires a type cast here: fn.bind doesn't seem to have an overload
  // for a generic number of parameters with possibly different types
  return (fn.bind as (thisArg: MyClass) => OmitThisParameter<F>)(instance)
}

function transformer<T extends Record<string, MyClassFn>>(
  funcs: T
): {[K in keyof T]: OmitThisParameter<T[K]>} {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(funcs)
     .map(([key, func]) => [key, func.bind(instance)])
  ) as {[K in keyof T]: OmitThisParameter<T[K]>}
}

// Usage
declare const f1: (this: MyClass, x: number, y: string) => number
declare const f2: (this: MyClass, x: number, y: boolean) => string
declare const f3: (this: MyClass) => void

// (x: number, y: string) => number
transform(f1)

// (x: number, y: boolean) => string
transform(f2)

// () => void
transform(f3)

// {
//   f1: (x: number, y: string) => number
//   f2: (x: number, y: boolean) => string
//   f3: () => void
// }
transformer({f1, f2, f3})
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#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)

Comment: Goodness, thank you so much, @cherryblossom!!! Going to try this shortly! Exactly what I was hoping for!!!

If you don't mind one addtl. question… how is it that `…args: never[]` works here? Obviously, on the other side of all this typing, the function signatures remain intact. I guess it's down to how that and `extends` interact?

Comment: Function parameters are contravariant, so all functions will be compatible with `...args: never[]`. If we used `...args: unknown[]`, it would mean that the caller can supply any arguments, such as `f1('oops this should be a number', true)` (`f1` should actually take a number and a string), which is why `f1` is not assignable to `(...args: unknown[]) => unknown`. On the other hand, function return types are covariant, which is why `unknown` is used. More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67717998/8289918

Comment: You could use `any[]` instead of `never[]` as well, which I've seen more often in this situation than `never[]`, but I tend to avoid `any` in my code.