# How to type pass through function decorators

Tags: typescript

The illustrative `enhanceFn` function below doesn't change the passed in function type `T` only wraps it with additional functionality - such as logging. `as unknown as T` overrides the return type and the `any[]` type is used in the args - is that the 'right' / 'canonical' way to do this, or is there a better way that I'm ignorant of?

```js
const enhanceFn = <T extends (...args: any[])=>any>(fn: T):T=>((...args: any[])=>{
    try{
        return fn(...args)
    } catch (e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}) as unknown as T

const fn = (value: string)=>{ throw new Error(value) }

const enhancedFn = enhanceFn(fn)

enhancedFn('throw this error')
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmAFgQzMOAxMMC8MA8AKvAB5QIAmEMAFAHQPIBOA5hAFwyoCeA2gLoBKHAD4eImgDMwnQoPaFRNeo1YcuYPkNEBvAFAxDMKE276jFmEzhQArk2zSVdZm0EGjAXxjBkUYIi0cILmloagkCAANnB0USAsNMEehp56noJc1LZgANZgIADu2MjUhHp6EdAw0ri0AG7IUbZwnNBMAJZgLMIiOsaITEUwYHCFMACiTENMNI3NwTBpleDVCChocBRYdeuo6FhSYO56e5vbYDQA5FCDw7cd1HDTIExXgkA)

Comment: It's been a hot while since I've used TypeScript productively but I think you should be able to extract the parameters into another generic parameter to remove the need for an ugly assertion at the end.

Comment: Oh well, it's a little more work than that. You get rid of the function generic parameter entirely and settle for the parameter and return types instead, something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvKlYw).

Comment: @hhearts - thank you, I'm so glad I asked the question.   Your solution is much better than mine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The illustrative `enhanceFn` function below doesn't change the passed in function type `T` only wraps it with additional functionality - such as logging

In the example, you provided, that's not quite the case. TS infers your `fn` type like this:

```ts
const fn = (value: string)=>{ throw new Error(value) }
//    ^? const fn: (value: string) => never
```

That's because functions which only have an exception-throwing path never complete, so the return type is [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#never).

Now let's look at the `enhanceFn` type:

First I'll extract the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) to separate the syntax concerns:

```ts
// const enhanceFn = <T extends (...args: any[])=>any>(fn: T):T=>((...args: any[])=>{
// This becomes:                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
type AnyFn = (...params: readonly any[]) => any;

const enhanceFn = <T extends AnyFn>(fn: T):T=>((...args: any[])=>{
    try{
        return fn(...args)
    } catch (e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}) as unknown as T
```

Now let's focus on what actually happens in the function body:

```ts
/* 1 */ {
/* 2 */     try{
/* 3 */         return fn(...args)
/* 4 */     } catch (e){
/* 5 */         console.log(e)
/* 6 */     }
/* 7 */ }
```

On line 3, the function provided as the original argument to the [higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) is invoked with the arguments which are provided to the returned function.

This happens inside a `try` block, so if an exception is thrown in `fn`, control is passed to the `catch` block at line 4.

On line 5 in the catch block, the exception is logged to the console, and that concludes the [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement.

So, if an exception is thrown, the function does not return `T`, but rather returns `undefined` because — in JavaScript — when there is no `return` statement in a function, `undefined` is returned as the default value (it is the absence of value).

> I could mention the [`void`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#void) type here, but that's a different discussion. There are many questions on-site which already cover it.

The refactored version of the HOF (with your error-throwing function) would look like this:

```ts
type AnyFn = (...params: readonly any[]) => any;

function returnResultOrLogException <Fn extends AnyFn>(
  fn: Fn,
): (...params: Parameters<Fn>) => ReturnType<Fn> | undefined {
  return (...params) => {
    try{
      return fn(...params);
    }
    catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }
  };
}

function throwErrorMessage (message: string): never {
  throw new Error(message);
}

const resultFn = returnResultOrLogException(throwErrorMessage);
//    ^? const resultFn: (message: string) => undefined

const result = resultFn('throw this error');
//    ^? const result: undefined
```

Here's a [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAYnKBeKAKAdDsBDAJzwFsBnALigIjwBMB7OAGxCjwQG0BdASjQD42CANwAoUQDMArnADGwAJaMqEYFIJwAShFJSmwAPIEAMvQDmAUQAesiGEXKAPMigQrwCHFqlYCZPwxRKCgJOEpkABpRHkpsXEISCigABQTiVQgCUmc4fj5UQW01DQAVcAgcwQAfKBlaCAkFOAhaKABvIJVilDisfCIyfMEO4ODgAhAR0eDqbpC4Xv7EnjFpgF9O4Nk8YFkAC0w3Pinp2UZSeiYILCZzDCPV0Y3gtbENyRl5JRRgPYJ6ADuFgI-wIAFkdKQ8GZoBh0qQoTDKKRxk0zDEoM0AG6ZdqdX7-AGYiBE4GguGQ6EQFaid5nOAolS6fQudCzdRaHR6QwmczWWz2b4YAmAsn0cGUmE0gD00umAD0APziemM6jM4BoJnc5AYADkIqJvwUPkyoL1MrloyVoiAA) for the code above.

To learn about why the return type becomes `undefined` and not `undefined | never`, see the answers to the question [How does the never type work in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67713566/438273).

Lastly, keep in mind that if you provide a function to the HOF which returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and that function rejects (which is not the same as throwing an exception), the `try...catch` won't catch the rejected promise. For that, you'll need [`Promise.prototype.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) or you'll need to [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the returned promise so that if it does reject, the rejection will be converted to an exception.

Answer (score 2):

you can get that answer here: [TS decorator to wrap function definition in try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73066433/ts-decorator-to-wrap-function-definition-in-try-catch)

```
function Execpetion (methodName: string) {
    return (target: any, nameMethod: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {      
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value 
        descriptor.value = async function (...args: any[]) {
            try {
                const executionMethod = await originalMethod.apply(this, args) 
                return executionMethod
            }  catch (error) {
                return errorWrapper(error as Error)
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

in your class

```
class TestController {

    @Execpetion('TestController')
    public async handler (teste: any) {
        
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        data: 'nothing'
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Christian, that will work if one is using classes.