# TS decorator to wrap function definition in try catch

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-decorator

Is it possible to use TS decorator to wrap a function definition into a try-catch block. I don't want to use try-catch in every function so I was thinking maybe decorators can help.
For example

```
function examleFn(errorWrapper: any) {
  try{
    // some code
  } catch (err) {
  errorWrapper(err)
  }
}
```

Something like this can be done in a decorator so that it can be used for other functions too.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do try-catch at a higher level in the call chain?

Comment: @TomPrice its a controller function in nodejs, can’t go on higher level.

Comment: Have you looked at error handling middleware?  https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: @TomPrice yeah, I am using one but, the reason I am doing this is that I am using the next function in jest to test my negative test cases. Now that I have passed the error in next(err) I can use it in jest. Not sure if it is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot decorate functions.

[TypeScript's implementation of decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators) can only apply to classes, class methods, class accessors, class properties, or class method parameters.   The relevant [proposal for JavaScript decorators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) (at Stage 3 of [the TC39 Process](https://tc39.es/process-document/) as of today, 2022-07-21) also does not allow for decorating functions.

[Function decorators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/blob/8ca65c046dd5e9aa3846a1fe5df343a6f7efd9f8/EXTENSIONS.md#function-decorators-and-annotations) are mentioned as [possible extensions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/blob/8ca65c046dd5e9aa3846a1fe5df343a6f7efd9f8/EXTENSIONS.md#possible-extensions) to the decorator proposal, but are not currently part of any proposal for either TypeScript or JavaScript.

---

You can, of course, call a decorator-like function on another function, but this is just a higher-order function and not a decorator per se, and it won't affect the original function declaration:

```
const makeErrorWrapper = <T,>(errorHandler: (err: any) => T) =>
    <A extends any[], R>(fn: (...a: A) => R) =>
        (...a: A): R | T => {
            try {
                return fn(...a);
            } catch (err) {
                return errorHandler(err);
            }
        };
```

The `makeErrorWrapper` function takes an error handler and returns a new function that wraps other functions with that error handler:

```
const errToUndefined = makeErrorWrapper(err => undefined);
```

So now `errToUndefined` is a function wrapper.  Let's say we have the following function which throws errors:

```
function foo(x: string) {
    if (x.length > 3) throw new Error("THAT STRING IS TOO LONG");
    return x.length;
}
// function foo(x: string): number
```

If you call it directly, you can get runtime errors:

```
console.log(foo("abc")); // 3
console.log(foo("abcde")); //  THAT STRING IS TOO LONG
```

Instead you can wrap it:

```
const wrappedFoo = errToUndefined(foo);
// const wrappedFoo: (x: string) => number | undefined
```

Now `wrappedFoo` is a new function that behaves like `foo` and takes the same parameter list as `foo`, but returns `number | undefined` instead of just `number`:

```
console.log(wrappedFoo("abc")) // 3
console.log(wrappedFoo("abcde")) // undefined
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwNYFMCiAnDIMHUMIAOhKGMAvDADwAqANAHwAUp2GAEgmACYA2pALhgssQrgE8AlBQYwa08gwBQMVdQCCMFAA8oKHhBgSA2gF06MAErMAZmCFMAdM4RD1C2ZY8q1vpy7dJIUsYAB85GRgAbx9fOJgoDHFo2Pi0jBQoAFcMMBg7f0cESQBuVLSYAF8YYAQoYAALYVZpGIqKjOzcrSwcTh5+DBEMUvK0yrHVSrKlUEhYVhoQAFUeFBsASzAUbgp4ZHRevAJiUmHIrLXN7e5RpRtL4CgN8HyQECZtIWgMLYBzVqpDY2YTaRz8MB-KBNWQAZmk0OwAHcYNsUZg2EwAEQ0djqGgwADKNEsAEkAHIAcRgpMJcgA8vSYAAZelUrGjXydHJ5MEQqENMoTAD0wvyj2erxs70+30S-yCqKycAARqQlEpEsk2mo5hAQPxwSA-kxpR8sQgVcAOaUYKKYLDUnqDSgjSazdjLcBuCgbUKanVGs0sIDfM7DbxjcNbfbcfiiSSKdTaQymayqUoJrNwNAYEiTiRuAAxd57RYrK5bHam96je162D5oiFksgBxfGA-BWRMDKtVkcKXH3XHbZyAut1MJunYsyi1Wm12sWO8OuyMm6ctuden2L+1D9ZV7gapRAA)

Comment: What does `<T,>` mean?

Comment: It's declaring the function's generic type parameter `T` (the comma is only there to prevent the parser from being confused if you use TSX/JSX, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/32696475/2887218 )

Answer (score 2):

maybe this can help you, it took me a long time to do it, but here it is

```
function Execpetion (methodName: string) {
    return (target: any, nameMethod: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {      
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value 
        descriptor.value = async function (...args: any[]) {
            try {
                const executionMethod = await originalMethod.apply(this, args) 
                return executionMethod
            }  catch (error) {
                return errorWrapper(error as Error)
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

in your class

```
class TestController {

    @Execpetion('TestController')
    public async handler (teste: any) {
        
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        data: 'nothing'
      }
    }
}
```

with the parent function, you can modify and add to receive the errorPersonalized and instantiated type parameter... and on the return put it

Comment: Can someone explain how this addresses the question as asked? I understood the question to be asking to decorate a *function*, not a class method. @MehulChaturvedi, could you clarify? Thanks!